# Correct design to construct an object

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, constructor

I have a major design concern about my specific use-case in object construction.

I am constructing an object `MyMessage` based on the value of the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` object. For that purpose, of course, the `ObjectMapper` is used, so the actual construction snippet would look something like following:

```
JsonNode json = JsonLoader.fromResource("msg.json");           
MyMessage m = jsonMapper.treeToValue(json, MyMessage.class);
```

Here the `jsonMapper` variable is of the type `ObjectMapper`.

Now, I would like `MyMessage` to only be able to construct from a static factory method, and keep the actual constructor private (as it has way too many fields). So the preferred construction would like this:

```
MyMessage m = MyMessage.createFromJson(json);
```

Here a `json` variable is of type `JsonNode`.

And that is where the **problem** begins. Obviously, `ObjectMapper` instance is needed to construct the object from JSON, and I would try to avoid it being passed-in by the client code.

Now, making `ObjectMapper` as a private (static) field of `MyMessage` comes to mind, and have something like this:

```
private static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

private MyMessage(/* many fields */){/* ctor code */}

public MyMessage createFromJson(JsonNode json) {
    return jsonMapper.treeToValue(json, MyMessage.class)
}
```

But here the problem is that I want the `ObjectMapper` object to be singleton for my entire application, and used not only for constructing `MyMessage` object, but also different kind of `Message` objects such as `YourMessage`, `SomeOtherMessage`, etc.

The problem with having many (static) instances of ObjectMapper is that I will have very large number of different `Message` classes, and many instances per class. So this would be very memory inefficient.

**The Question**

What is the closest I can get to have both a singleton `ObjectMapper` and a static factory method? Or maybe you could suggest some other design idea (I don't know if a builder pattern could help somehow) that would suit my use-case?

Comment: Simple solution is you can have a non-private static object mapper. A bit more complex maybe if all Messages are inner classes of some other class, they can reference an object mapper from the outter class?

Comment: @aiguy A non-private static object mapper seems like a design flaw. Public fields are usually discouraged. No, messages are not inner classes, they are normal classes.

Comment: It kind of depends on what else your object mapper will be used for. For instance, if it is used only to read/write messages, I think a package private one is ok. If you want necessarily dependency injection you can try enclosing messages (or a common super class) in an outer class with a mapper.

Comment: It will be used only to construct messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you move away from the *static factory method* restriction, and have a `Factory` that creates your messages, and make that class have a reference to your singleton `ObjectMapper`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

final class MessagesFactory {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    // This constructor is a great candidate for DI
    MessagesFactory(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    <T extends Message> T createFromJson(
         final JsonNode json, final Class<T> messageClass
    ) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.treeToValue(json, clazz);
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you need it, you can do:

```
MyMessage m1 = messagesFactory.createFromJson(json, MyMessage.class);
MyMessage2 m2 = messagesFactory.createFromJson(otherJson, MyMessage2.class);
```